# jQuery does not run in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

This jQuery is not working in mobile but does perfectly work in Chrome emulator.

There is no error showing in the console. I tried it in the Android browser and in Chrome but it did not work. JavaScript is enabled.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var bodyh = jQuery("body").height();
    var windowh = jQuery(window).height();
    var diff = windowh - bodyh;
    var marginsize = (diff / 5) - 12;

    if (windowh > 563) {
        jQuery(".adjust-margin").css('margin-bottom', marginsize);
        jQuery(".adjust-margin-t").css('margin-bottom', marginsize);
    }    
});
```

Comment: What is the window height in the mobile device. Perhaps put an alert in your code to see.

Comment: see in iphone 6 or 6 plus window height is greate than body height plus its working chrome emulator.
http://www.responsinator.com/?url=shahid-test.herokuapp.com%2Fremote01%23

Comment: You'd probably be a lot better off using some [**responsive css**](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/), rather than JS.

Comment: yes but given that your code doesnt work and it is the only condition you test, I am jusy saying you should probably check it. see this too https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/741

Answer (score 0):

Great replacing jquery to get height of body and window with javascript it solve the problem seem out their is an issue to with jquery to work in mobile browser.

replace jquery

```
var bodyh = jQuery("body").height();
var windowh = jQuery(window).height();
```

with javascript

```
    var bodyh = document.body.clientHeight;
    var windowh = window.innerHeight;
```